# My Android Program Runs on Emulator, but not on Galaxy S3

Tags: android

When I run my program on Android Emulator, it runs, but on Samsung Galaxy S3, it won't.
I mean, when I install the .apk on my emulator, it's successful. when my emulator reboots, the app runs. but when I install it on galaxy s3, it successfully installed and I can open it without any problems, but when I reboot my galaxy s3, it won't automatically open.

I think it's because my android emulator uses Android Version 2.2 and my S3 is using Android Version 4.0.4

My app is simple; every time the phone starts, my program starts.

This app's SDK build is "4.1 API 16".

Here's my code.

**Manifest.xml**

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.onboot"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver android:name=".LaunchAppBroadcast"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name=".OnBoot"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_on_boot" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I got a java file.

**OnBoot.java**

```
public class OnBoot extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_on_boot);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_on_boot, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

and **LaunchAppBroadcast.java**

```
public class LaunchAppBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, OnBoot.class);
    intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent2);

}

 }
```

That's it. Once Again, this already works on android emulator.

And I made a new project again now using BUILD SDK "4.0 API 14", still it works with the emulator but not with my galaxy

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about what "does not work" means. If you get an exception or the app is force closed, post the LogCat.

Comment: Post your full manifest please.

Comment: you need to post the full logcat so we can see what error you are getting

Comment: @Tim, I do not get any errors, I can run it by click the "OnBoot" launcher icon without any problems, but when I reboot it, it won't run automatically. thanks tim

Comment: @tyczj , will try that, but as I said it does not have any errors. i don't get any error message when I reboot my s3

Comment: @EGHDK, thanks for your comment, by posting the full manifest, I managed to solve my problem. by changing `android:versionName="1.0"` to `android:versionName="4.0"`

Comment: Interesting... glad I could lead you to your solution.